# Can the Webform Table Element row span 2 cells

Tags: webforms

I created a webform and added a table element as per the information from [Webform Composites vs. Tables | Jacob Rockowitz](https://youtu.be/7cVIqySy5fs)

My table has 4 columns & 14 rows. The bottom 3 rows will only have 3 cells. I need to column span the 1st cell to span 2 columns on these 3 rows. As shown in the image below.

I believe the table is built using the twig template from the `table.html.twig` file in my custom theme. Is there a way to add a flag on the webform table element to indicate to the `table.html.twig` file that a td requires to be `<td colspan"amount">`. I hope this helps
[image: last table rows]

This was done by editing the code in Chromes DevTools as below.
[image: DevTools]

Can this **colspan="2"** be added within the Webforms Table element?